# How to scrape FULL page source code by VBA - cell limit problem

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I would like to scrape full page source code using VBA (without any other tools) and paste it into excel. However, due to cell limits biggest part of the source code is missing.

I'm using the code below:

```
Sub SCRAPE()
Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate "https://www.ng-news.net/best-budget-processor-for-super-budget-gaming-pc/"
                 Do While .Busy And .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
         Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:06")
       Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = .document.body.outerHTML
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

I was thinking about using Text Box instead of cell, but I don't know if (and HOW) I can set value of text box.

Other solution could be pre-setting delimitation whoch would devide source code after pasting, but it won't work as there is no "paste" method in the code really.

It would be probably possible to save the source code to txt file instead of in cell, but again- I need it to land in excel at the end, so again there will be problem with cell limitations.

Can you guys suggest some other solutions, or edit the code above so that I can get full source code?

Comment: You are correct, due to cell limitations, you cannot do that. Why do you need the full HTML from the page? you have access to the `.document` object, you could just use that and pull what you need from HTML. If you really need the full HTML, i would suggest writing a parser that breaks down the HTML and have it paste the results in a `range` rather than a `cell`

Comment: The reason I want full source code is that i need b_hotel_id value (here: 1098427) from https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/dream-catcher-plantation-resort.pl.html but I have no clue how to address it. So I thought to extract data in more manual way, after it's pasted in excel. Btw. what do you mean by "writing a parser that breaks down the HTML and have it paste the results in a range rather than a cell"?

Comment: You don't need to download the HTML for that. You are half way their. research `GetElementByTagName` or `GetElementById`. it should guide you to what you need

Comment: I've tried, but since this element is not visible in the website I can't find proper tag to refer to this object...

Comment: You can use `GetElementsByTagName("input")`. This will return you all **input** fields on the page (even if they are hidden). You can then loop through them until you find one with **hotel_id** as name and capture the `value` of that element. There are other ways to do this but might be worth getting use to what you can do with `.document` first